# Select option from dropdown and display in box

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dropdown with values in it which when selected should display that item in the `div` named `search_box`. I know that the idea here should be to use hooks, something which I have done already but I cannot get the selected value to display instead of the `Enter District` text in the `search_box`. I tried console logging to see if the selected value was displaying or not but since it isn't, I'm pretty sure I have messed up somewhere.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './search.css';
import { IoMdArrowDropdown } from 'react-icons/io';
import { GoTriangleUp } from 'react-icons/go';
import data from '../../../../data.json';

const SearchBox = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState(null);

    const onSelect = (value) => {
        setDropDownValue(value);
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    return (
        <div className="box_district">
            <div className="district_caption">District</div>
            <div className="block_drop">
                <div className="district_dropdown">
                    <div className="search_box">            //search box
                        Enter District                      //This is where the value should get selected
                    </div>
                    <div className="drop_icon" onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}>
                        {open ? <GoTriangleUp size={"22px"} /> : <IoMdArrowDropdown size={"30px"} />}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={open ? "open_options" : "options"}>
                    {data.map((countries) => <div className="select_options" onClick={val => onSelect(val)}>    //This is where the options get rendered
                        {countries.name}
                        {console.log(dropDownValue)}
                    </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

[image]

The dropdown goes away as functioned as soon as I click on something but that's how far this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor changes you have to do here is
used:

```
<div className="search_box">
  {dropDownValue === null ? "Enter District" : dropDownValue}
</div>
```

and

```
<div className="select_options" onClick={() => onSelect(countries?.name)}>
                {countries.name}
                {console.log(dropDownValue)}
              </div>
```

Comment: This works but can you please explain the role of the ? operator in countries?.name

Comment: In simple word ? operator check if countries have data then go next and find name if countries have no data so it not going to find name and not giving any error like cannot find name in countries. i felt that it is awesome feature in react